# how can I get value of row in table, when I click in botton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, with innumerable rows, when I click the button, I need to get the line id that the button is clicked on. How can I do this?
my attempt code:

```
function teste(){
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).parent().find('.idServico').html();
    alert(name);
});
```

}

my table that my js generate:

```
tabelaResultado.innerHTML += `
    <tr>
        <td class="idServico">${idServico}</td>
        <td>${dataEntradaServico}</td>
        <td>${dataSaidaServico}</td>
        <td>${cpfPessoa}</td>
        <td>${idStatus}</td>
        <td>${descricaoServico}</td>
        <td class="actions tirarCor">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/updateService">Visualizar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="/updateService">Editar</a>
            <button id="botaoExcluir" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="teste()"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Excluir</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: There is no line ID in your markup. Which variable refers to the line ID?

Comment: I need to get idServico value

Comment: Also, note that you are potentially reusing the ID `botaoExcluir`. IDs must be unique in a document, so you should probably give it a class instead, or ensure that it is unique.

Comment: ohh, its true, good point, I'll change

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline event handler from your button and setup an event listener with jQuery. Then you can use `$(this)` to refer to the button being clicked, `.closest()` to traverse upward to the parent `<tr>`, and `.find()` to get the `<td>` with the class `idServico`:

```
$('button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.idServico').html();
    alert(name);
})
```

If the rows are being added dynamically, you should instead use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click' ,'button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs' ,function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.idServico').html();
    alert(name);
})
```

Comment: just a remark - looking at his code he is creating rows dynamically, so I would suggest using a delegated listener

Comment: @Jamesonthedog Fair point. If so, the OP can change the `$('button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs').click(function(){` to `$(document).on('click' ,'button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs' ,function(){`

Comment: this code: $('button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.idServico').html();
    alert(name);
}) show nothing

Comment: @MatheusAlcântara If your rows are being generated dynamically, then try what I suggested in my comment above

Comment: works!!!! $(document).on('click' ,'button.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs' ,function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.idServico').html();
    alert(name);
}); thanks!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll update my answer to include the code in the comment. If you found the answer useful, consider upvoting and/or accepting it.